# Code content is appearing out of order in Razor app

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have three `if`s (have also tried `span`, `table`, and `div`) and I expect them to display in the order they appear in the code, like `1,2,3`. Instead the first two statements seem to never stay in order.

CODE

```
<div class="row">
   @if (item.PastElo.Rank != "None")
   {
        <img src="~/Content/badges/@(item.PastElo.Rank).png" alt="@(item.PastElo.Rank)" />
   }
   @if (item.PastElo1.Rank != "None")
   {
        <img src="~/Content/badges/@(item.PastElo1.Rank).png" alt="@(item.PastElo1.Rank)" />
   }
   @if (item.PastElo2.Rank != "None")
   {
        <img src="~/Content/badges/@(item.PastElo2.Rank).png" alt="@(item.PastElo2.Rank)" />
   }
</div>
```

Now as the code states, if a certain condition is not met it will not display, but regardless of that my first two div's are always flipped.

If I had a set of data such as

```
None
Apple 
Banana
Peach
```

and I had three iterations of the loop above with data such as

```
// loop 1
PastElo = Apple
PastElo1 = Banana
PastElo2 = Peach

// loop 2
PastElo = Apple
PastElo1 = Banana
PastElo2 = None

// loop 3
PastElo = Apple
PastElo1 = None
PastElo2 = Peach
```

It would display like this.

```
Banana Apple Peach
Banana Apple
Apple Peach
```

The first two statements are always appearing reverse. I have tried using divs, spans, a table, and even jQuery to insertBefore with no luck.

Why is this occurring?

Using MVC and Razer.

**Actual image of issue.** (Notice each symbol has a Numeral in it, the Numerals should be appearing in order of I, II, III if not `null`). Arrow'ed the II before I in the image.

[image]

**Outputted HTML Sample of line Two** (showing the HTML out of order as well)

```
<div class="row">
   <img src="/Content/badges/s2diamond.png" alt="s2diamond" height="37" width="37" />
   <img src="/Content/badges/s1gold.png" alt="s1gold" height="37" width="37" />
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(string Filter, string searchString, string Sort)
        {
            ViewBag.champ1 = new SelectList(db.championLists, "ID", "Name");
            ViewBag.champ2 = new SelectList(db.championLists, "ID", "Name");
            ViewBag.champ3 = new SelectList(db.championLists, "ID", "Name");
            ViewBag.elo = new SelectList(db.eloLists, "ID", "rank");
            ViewBag.rank = new SelectList(db.rankLists, "ID", "rank");
            ViewBag.role1 = new SelectList(db.roleLists, "ID", "lane");
            ViewBag.role2 = new SelectList(db.roleLists, "ID", "lane");
            ViewBag.s1elo = new SelectList(db.PastEloes, "ID", "Rank");
            ViewBag.s2elo = new SelectList(db.PastEloes, "ID", "Rank");
            ViewBag.s3elo = new SelectList(db.PastEloes, "ID", "Rank");
            ViewBag.s4elo = new SelectList(db.PastEloes, "ID", "Rank");

            // !filter and !sort
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Sort) && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(Filter)))
            {
                return View(db.Users.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.name));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the controller code which binds these properties? Are you sure the problem is not there?

Comment: I am still newer to MVC, but how would the Controller be in charge of this? Maybe I am missing a concept of .NET MVC. (I will post the Controller too!)

Comment: I'd advise checking the outputted HTML. Something like a `float` in CSS can easily make things appear in a different order than the HTML.

Comment: @Chris Right now `float:none` within my HTML.

Comment: @Austin, it should not. But it looks like values of `PastElo` and `PastElo1` are just mixed up. Wanted to make sure you have eliminated this option

Comment: @Andrei oh if that's the case that isn't possible. I just return `Users` with .Include for each `PastElo`. No other Bindings or anything

Comment: @Austin: float was just one example that sprang to mind. Have you confirmed the HTML is out of order and not just the rendering on screen? (Apologies if you have but with something like this that looks like it should work its best to be very sure about what steps you have and haven't ruled out properly)

Comment: @Chris just looked in the source code and indeed they are out of order. I appreciate the help thus far!

Comment: @Chris The weird is that if I just rearrange the top two `if`'s then it all appears in order... Do you think that is okay if this always happens? I have no idea what else could be causing this.

Comment: @Austin, check your data source and mappings to it. Everything points to just brocken data

Comment: @Andrei I am, I just can't seem to find anything :(

Comment: If the HTML is out of order then that would lead me to believe either the data isn't what you think it is or that it is using a different version of the code than you expect (eg an older version due to caching or bad deploy or something). Can you run through this in debug mode to confirm what order it is running things in?